# jquery to json problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I would really appreciate any help on this problem that I have spent many hours trying to solve.  I have a jquery object that I created from elements on a web page:

```html
var get_article = $('title, p, img');
```

When I console.log this, I get a nice, clean list of the elements and their index values.  What I would like to do is add each element to a json object along with their index value and contents.  I have tried this:

```html
article = new Array();

$.each(get_article, function(){
  $('title').each(function() {
    var title_items = {
      node:   $(this).index(''),
      html_element:   "title",
      content:  $(this).text()
    };
    article.push(JSON.stringify(title_items));
  });  
  $('p').each(function() {
    var p_items = {
      node:   $(this).index(''),
      html_element:   "p",
      content:  $(this).text()
    };
    article.push(JSON.stringify(p_items));  
  });
  
  $('img').each(function() {
    var img_items = {
      node:   $(this).index(''),
      html_element:   "img",
      content:  $(this).attr("src")
    };
    article.push(JSON.stringify(img_items));
  });
});
```

When I console.log the json object (article), all of the data is correct except the node values in the json object (article) are all over the place and they don't show the same as the index value in the original jquery object (get_article).  Also, the data begins to repeat itself, so I have more nodes than was in the original jquery object (get_article).  Please help!

Thanks all for your help.  I was able to solve the problem using this code.  Looking at your responses made me see that I needed to try another way.  This is what worked for me:

```js
for (i = 0; i < get_article.length; i++) {
    if ($(get_article[i]).is('title')) {
    var title_items = {
 node:  i,
 html_element:  "title",
 content: $(get_article[i]).text()
};
article.push(JSON.stringify(title_items));
}
    if ($(get_article[i]).is('p')) {
    var p_items = {
 node:  i,
 html_element:  "p",
 content: $(get_article[i]).text()
};
article.push(JSON.stringify(p_items));
}
    if ($(get_article[i]).is('img')) {
    var img_items = {
 node:  i,
 html_element:  "img",
 content: $(get_article[i]).attr("src")
};
article.push(JSON.stringify(img_items));
}
};
```

Comment: Please supply a sample of the input values and the JSON output for those input values.

Comment: I would use .map.

Comment: As requested, I've added some more details jwpfox.  And could you give me an example of how I would use the .map function in this example KevinB.  I really appreciate you guys' help.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually using `get_article` anywhere in your code.

```
$.each(get_article, function(){
    $('title').each(function() {
        var title_items = {
            // ...
        };
        article.push(JSON.stringify(title_items));
    });
    // ....
});
```

is exactly the same as

```
$('title').each(function() {
    var title_items = {
        // ...
    };
    article.push(JSON.stringify(title_items));
});
```

It's hard to say for sure since you haven't provided enough details, but perhaps what you want is something like:

```
$.each(get_article, function(){
    $(this).find('title').each(function() {
        var title_items = {
            // ...
        };
        article.push(JSON.stringify(title_items));
    });
    // ....
});
```

That's still not going to have the exact same effect as simply logging to the console, though. The order of the elements will be different because in the code you're first getting all the titles, then all the paragraphs, and then all the images. When you console.log the jQuery output, it's not segregating the elements by their type but simply showing them in their DOM order.

For example, if the DOM has

- title 1
- paragraph 1
- title 2

the console.log will show

1. title 1
2. paragraph 1
3. title 2

while the (fixed) code will show

1. title 1
2. title 2
3. paragraph 1

Comment: You're exactly right, my code is segregating the elements by type, but i would like to get them in correct DOM order.  Would it be better to try something like this  for (i = 0; i < get_article.length; i++) {
    if (get_article[i].hasTagName('p')) { ...   I tried it earlier, but couldn't make it work.  Please see the json output that I added to the original post.